# Error loading .hs file using GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm a complete beginner with Haskell. So far I've downloaded the GHC. I know how to use it via the terminal by typing

```
$ ghci
```

also I have made a file called test.hs with my own code. I would like to run the file in ghci via terminal but i keep getting this error.

[image]

I have saved the test.hs on a file on my desktop. Im assuming i have to state the file path but i don't know how!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that you are on the correct folder before loading it and the file exists? `ghci` is the command line interpreter so you can load a file after calling it by typing `:l test.hs` .

Comment: How can i specify the file path for the source file test.hs?

Comment: I found the problem. I was using TextEdit to save my source file and the .sh extension was not being applied. Got text wrangler and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is on your desktop, use

```
ghci ~/Desktop/test.hs
```

Note that this is not really a Haskell question, but a shell question (and the path is specific to Mac OS X).